# Switch Laptop from windows 10 to Linux

Tags: xubuntu

I want to switch a spare laptop I have from Windows 10 to Linux. I don't wish to keep windows on there at all and have nothing on there to back up. Can anyone point me towards a guide that shows me how to do this please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had an old Dell Inspiron 8600 laptop running (Windows) that wouldn't boot.      I got hold of a Live distro in my case it was Puppy (Slacko) 5.5/5.6 there are many others e.g. Knoppix 7.7.1. Boot up into the Live CD. Under System find GParted and click on it. It displays all of your partitions. I selected my largest one.  A popup windows displays. I clicked format. I selected the number that would format everything. Click Apply. Select you next partition until you're thru. Remember I used Puppy Linux. 5.5.or 5.6 because of the size of my RAM.